# pandas manipulate dataframe shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

I have a dataframe, `df`:

```
    x        hour     y
0   511746   08    53960
1   959377   11    85830
```

I wish to manipulate this to the form:

```
    type     hour  metric
0   x        08    511746
1   y        08    53960
2   x        11    959377
3   y        11    85830
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pd.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
In [182]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='hour', value_vars=['x','y'], 
                  var_name='type', value_name='metric')
Out[182]:
  hour type  metric
0   08    x  511746
1   11    x  959377
2   08    y   53960
3   11    y   85830
```